# Fat library in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode7

I'm having problem with building fat library for Boost with Xcode toolchain. Building itself works fine after some fixes in script but when I use it in project I'm getting linker error:

```
ld: in boost.framework/boost(atomic_lockpool.o), building for iOS simulator, but linking in object file built for OSX, for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Also I found [same problem](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13795) at Apple Developer Forums but there is no any solution just people reporting same problem.

`lipo -info` output:

```
Architectures in the fat file: boost.framework/boost are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it requires additional flag `cxxflags="-miphoneos-version-min=7.0"` for `bjam`.

Here is how `bjam` call looks like now (for simulator):

```
bjam -j$(CORES) --build-dir=$(IPHONESIM_BUILD_DIR) --stagedir=$(IPHONESIM_STAGE_DIR) --toolset=darwin-$(IPHONE_SDKVERSION)~iphonesim cxxflags="-miphoneos-version-min=7.0" architecture=x86 target-os=iphone macosx-version=iphonesim-$(IPHONE_SDKVERSION) link=static
```

Comment: John, where did you put this?  I'm using a gist build script originally from Pete Goodlife, and I added it to the cxx flags, but it made no difference.  Clean rebuilds and all.

Comment: Gave you the up votes already, but now it works I can say thank you as well.

Comment: @JohnTracid I am facing the same problem but with cryptopp build script ,Can you please tell the patch required in the script. The script path is https://github.com/debris/cryptopp-ios/blob/master/cryptopp/builder.sh